# ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: add-theme-support

I'm experiencing `ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR` when uploading a WordPress Theme. I had transferred the site to a new host and I think I had done everything all right. When uploading a theme, this is what comes up:

> This site can’t be reached The webpage at https://mysitename.com/wp-admin/update.php?action=upload-theme might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
>
> ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR

What could be the problem? How do I resolve it?

Comment: Can you try different browser?

Comment: I tried using a different browser but still couldn't. Anyway, I found a way. I uploaded the theme straight into the file manager from the hosting cpanel.